# How to draw Bargraph using PHP

Tags: php

I want to draw Bar Graph of Marks of Student out of 100 the Marks are stored in MY SQL database and using php we show there marks in Text
we got the marks stored in 
Php variable

```
$eng
$math
$phy
$ip
$pedu
$chem
```

but now we want to show the marks in graph how to do that
see [Here](http://www.chatat.tk/dav)
its the developer site ....
try pseudo Roll Number 1000 or 11988
Graph should be like this
[Graph](http://www.chatat.tk/dav/graph.html)

Answer (score 4):

Have fun: [pchart class PHP](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/)

> pChart is a PHP class oriented framework designed to create aliased charts. Most of todays chart libraries have a cost, our project is intended to be free. Data can be retrieved from SQL queries, CSV files, or manually provided. This project is still under development and new features or fix are made every week.
>
> Focus has been put on rendering quality introducing an aliasing algorithm to draw eye candy graphics. Rendering speed has been dramatically enhanced since the first version, we'll still continue optimising the code!